# Como usar bien soundex?

Tags: php, mysql

He estado haciendo unas búsquedas de la palabra 'tabla' en una columna `título` con soundex y no aparece nada, tampoco con 'tablas' o con 'table' pero si la consulta es con LIKE '%tabla%' aparece de inmediato.

Que está mal?

```
$busqueda = "tabla";

$data = $connection->query("
    SELECT titulo 
    from `posts` 
    where soundex(`titulo`) like soundex('$busqueda') ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Faltaría la tabla para verificar bien las cosas, pero, teniendo esta tabla

```
create table cosas (
   id integer,
   nombre varchar(25)
);

insert into cosas 
values (1, 'tabla'), (2, 'mesa'), (3, 'silla'), 
       (4, 'banco'), (5, 'libro'), (6, 'revista') ;
```

Puedo realizar la consulta de este modo (sin like)

```
select nombre 
from cosas 
where soundex("mesa") = soundex(nombre);
```

Teniendo este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excorpion entonces mi consulta no está mala? cómo te digo para ver si la tabla estaba buena, use LIKE '%%' y efectivamente me encontró la palabra, cabe mencionar que la columna `titulo` es full text

Comment: Necesito que me des un ejemplo de tu tabla para emularla y probar TU consulta. Si haces eso, edita tu publicación añadiendola y te confirmo.

Comment: En teoría hace una consulta muy parecida a **LIKE** tradicional, pero fonéticamente, es decir que te regresaría un registro parecido a como suena lo que le estas consultando, pero OJO de momento solo funciona en  **ingles** checa este [ejemplo](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-soundex-function.php)

Comment: Excorpión ya se que pasa.                                       'tabla' esta dentro de una frase, cuando escribo esta frase completa: soundex('tabla, mesa y silla') aparece la frase completa.                                         Cómo puedo encontrar la palabra 'tabla' independiente de que este en una frase, usando soundex?

Comment: Acabas de responderte solo. El uso de '%LIKE%' hace exactamente lo que buscas. Buscar la palabra/sonido que se asemeje a lo solicitado

Comment: Excorpion '%LIKE%' no muestra nada si el usuario se equivoca buscando 'tabls' o 'tablas';   ¿Sabes como usar soundex en este caso? y match against tampoco muestra nada

Comment: Fonéticamente hablando, solo podrías validar los ingresos vs un diccionario. 'tabls' es un ingreso incorrecto, y no es una palabra como tal, por lo que el ingreso de 'tabls' es tan incorrecto como 'xhsd'...

Comment: Excorpion y 'tablas'?

Comment: Eso lo puedes probar simplemente XD

Answer (score 2):

La clave soundex busca parecidos foneticos, por lo que si usas un like esa consulta no funcionara, deberas usar la consulta como where soundex("d") = soundex(campo) ya que al hacer esto estarias comparando la clave soundex generada, para que tengas una mejor visual del tema te recomiendo hacer algo como.

```
SELECT  
  soundex(titulo), titulo
FROM posts
WHERE soundex(titulo) = soundex($titulo)
```

claro teniendo en cuenta la seguridad,  esto lo que haria seria comparar las dos claves generadas

la clave soundex para la palabra casa es C200 y la clave de caza es la la mimsa C200, es decir todas las palabras que foneticamente suenen igual van a tener la misma clave soundex.

Comment: Luis Toscano Castilla tienes razón, también use = ,  ahora tengo otra pregunta ¿Sabes como usar soundex para encontrar una palabra dentro de una frase?

Comment: en ese caso seria mas complejo ya que soundex funciona sobre palabras, lo que necesitarias ahi seria una busqueda heuristica y te tocaria programar alguna funcion que tokenize la frase es decir que separe las palabras por frases y ahi si poder aplicar soundex, me parece que seria una tarea mas compleja, pero si se podria hacer mas o menos de esa forma.